# ML .NET MulticlassEvaluationMetrics always evaluates 0 on testSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, machine-learning, ml.net

I have been following this example from ML .NET tutorials: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/machine-learning/tutorials/GitHubIssueClassification

And built my own version of this example which reads data from .xlsx (different dataset) and splits it into training and testing sets. It works well and makes correct predictions, but I can't for the life of me figure out why evaluation metrics (every parameter) always show 0 when I feed _testSet into it. When I feed _trainSet it evaluates to 1 which is expected.

Even if I set TestFraction == 0.5 it still evaluates to 0.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ML;

namespace Test.Repository
{
    public class SearchEntry
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchPrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
        public string Topic;
    }

    public class Googler
    {
        private static string _appPath => Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
        public string SourceExcel { get; set; } = @"..\..\..\..\Test.Repository\model\in_data.xlsx";
        public string ModelSavePath { get; set; } = @"..\..\..\..\Test.Repository\model\model";
        public double TestFraction { get; set; } = 0.2d;
        private static IDataView _trainingDataView;
        private static MLContext _mlContext;
        private static ITransformer _trainedModel;
        private static IEstimator<ITransformer> pipeline;
        private static PredictionEngine<SearchEntry, SearchPrediction> _predEngine;
        private static List<SearchEntry> _trainSet;
        private static List<SearchEntry> _testSet;

        public void LoadModelData()
        {
            _mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
            var dt = Heplers.Excel.Query(SourceExcel, "SELECT * FROM [data$]");
            var searchEntries = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => new SearchEntry { Topic = (string)r["Topic"], Subject = (string)r["Subject"] });
            var dataview = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(searchEntries);
            var split = _mlContext.Data
                .TrainTestSplit(dataview, testFraction: TestFraction,
                samplingKeyColumnName: "Topic");
            _trainSet = _mlContext.Data
                .CreateEnumerable<SearchEntry>(split.TrainSet, reuseRowObject: false).ToList();
            _testSet = _mlContext.Data
                .CreateEnumerable<SearchEntry>(split.TestSet, reuseRowObject: false).ToList();
            _trainingDataView = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<SearchEntry>(_trainSet);
        }

        public void ProcessData()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"=============== Processing Data ===============");
            pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Topic", outputColumnName: "Label")
                            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName: "Subject", outputColumnName: "SubjectFeaturized"))
                            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "SubjectFeaturized"))
                            .AppendCacheCheckpoint(_mlContext);
            Console.WriteLine($"=============== Finished Processing Data ===============");
        }

        public void BuildAndTrainModel()
        {
            var trainingPipeline = pipeline
                    .Append(_mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaNonCalibrated("Label", "Features"))
                    .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
            Console.WriteLine($"=============== Training the model  ===============");
            _trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(_trainingDataView);
            Console.WriteLine($"=============== Finished Training the model Ending time: {DateTime.Now.ToString()} ===============");
        }
        public void Evaluate()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"=============== Evaluating to get model's accuracy metrics - Starting time: {DateTime.Now.ToString()} ===============");
            var testDataView = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<SearchEntry>(_testSet);
            var testMetrics = _mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Evaluate(_trainedModel.Transform(testDataView));
            Console.WriteLine($"=============== Evaluating to get model's accuracy metrics - Ending time: {DateTime.Now.ToString()} ===============");
            Console.WriteLine($"*************************************************************************************************************");
            Console.WriteLine($"*       Metrics for Multi-class Classification model - Test Data     ");
            Console.WriteLine($"*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"*       MicroAccuracy:    {testMetrics.MicroAccuracy:0.###}");
            Console.WriteLine($"*       MacroAccuracy:    {testMetrics.MacroAccuracy:0.###}");
            Console.WriteLine($"*       LogLoss:          {testMetrics.LogLoss:#.###}");
            Console.WriteLine($"*       LogLossReduction: {testMetrics.LogLossReduction:#.###}");
            Console.WriteLine($"*************************************************************************************************************");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
*************************************************************************************************************
*       Metrics for Multi-class Classification model - Test Data     
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*       MicroAccuracy:    0
*       MacroAccuracy:    0
*       LogLoss:          
*       LogLossReduction: NaN
*************************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: How big is the training data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched

```
var split = _mlContext.Data
                .TrainTestSplit(dataview, testFraction: TestFraction, samplingKeyColumnName: "Topic");
```

To

```
var split = _mlContext.Data
               .TrainTestSplit(dataview, testFraction: TestFraction);
```

With samplingKeyColumnName: "Topic" my Test Set would only have 2 unique Topics, without it had 6. Thus poor metrics.

But I still don't like the result. I have 10 unique Topics in total, it feels like Test Set must have at least some entries for each Topic. Microsoft.ML TrainTestSplit does not seem to guarantee that.

Wrote a custom splitter:

```
        private (List<SearchEntry> TrainSet, List<SearchEntry> TestSet) TrainTestSplit(List<SearchEntry> searchEntries, double testFraction)
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            var testSet = searchEntries.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => new { Random = rand.Next(), Entry = r })
                .OrderBy(r => r.Random)
                .Select(r => r.Entry)
                .GroupBy(r => r.Topic)
                .Select(r => r.Take((int)Math.Ceiling(searchEntries.Where(e => e.Topic == r.Key).Count() * testFraction)))
                .SelectMany(r => r)
                .ToList();
            var trainSet = searchEntries.Except(testSet).ToList();
            return (trainSet, testSet);
        }
```